# leaflet hide layer on the map in the initial view

Tags: leaflet, qgis

I am new to Leaflet. I am using QGIS2Leaf plugin to build a webmap with several layers, but I only want one or two layers to display when the map initially open. In the HTML doc QGIS2Leaf plugin creates for me it says:

//add comment sign to hide this layer on the map in the initial view.

I cannot figure out what the comment sign being referred to is. Please help.

Comment: Does it means to comment out the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're referring to the javascript comment sign: `//`. There are two ways to comment in javascript, single line and multiline. To comment a single line you prepend a double slash: `//`. In the example below `b` never gets declared:

```
var a = 1;
// var b = 2;
var c = 3;
```

To comment multiple lines you prepend `/*` and append `*/` to the lines you want to comment. In the example below `b` and `c` never get declared:

```
var a = 1;
/* var b = 2;
var c = 3; */
var d = 4;
```

Or equivalent:

```
var a = 1;
/*
var b = 2;
var c = 3;
*/
var d = 4;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar